# LLBLGen nested select

Tags: sql, llblgenpro, llblgen

How can I make a nested select statment with LLBLGen?

I have the following sql statement.

Select * from Users where User.UserId 
in (select ManagerId from LnkUserManagers)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a FieldCompareSetPredicate:

http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/hh_goto.htm#Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/Filtering%20and%20Sorting/gencode_filteringpredicateclasses_adapter.htm#FieldCompareSetPredicate